# jQuery validation: live and ajax val not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I know dat debugging is a task apart. But after i've spend tens of hours trying to get the code exactly right I've really no clue at all how to fix it.

I have a script that validates a webform. [Live demo here](http://dennishunink.nl/terugkomapp/docent.php)

The web form uses autocomplete for most of the fields. In the validation, only values that are in a database are accepted, the same database that is used for autocomplete. 
When a field as an error it turns red. 
There are also two depend fields; when `klas` isn't filled in correctly, `leerling` is not accessible.

So far so good. But there are a couple of issues; most of them present themselves only in IE of FF (strangely enough not on my mac). Hopefully some of you can help me out here.

1. When a field is not valid, and you try to correct, you can't type more than 1 character at a time.(all browsers). This makes the form kind of unusable.
2. When the date field is marked invalid and you're selecting an date afterwards, the field is still marked invalid.
3. It looks like IE and FF on Windows don't validate `on submit`; safari on mac does.

I would really appreciated if you could help me out; specially on the points 1 and 3.

See the live demo  [Live demo here](http://dennishunink.nl/terugkomapp/docent.php)

The script is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newAp").validate({               
        validClass: 'succes',
        ignore: '#opmerking',
        errorContainer: '#newap-error',
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#" + $(element).attr("data-dependency")).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#ll-naamErrorLabel").show();
            $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
            $("#" + $(element).attr("data-dependency")).removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#ll-naamErrorLabel").hide();
            $("#ll-naam").focus();
        },
        rules: {
            docent: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                remote: "handlers/validationInSqlArray.php"
            },
            'vak': {
                required: true,
                remote: "handlers/validationInSqlArray.php"
            },
            'klas': {
                required: true,
                remote: "handlers/validationInSqlArray.php",
            },
            'll-naam': {
                required: true
            },
            'datum': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            docent: {
                required: "Vul uw achternaam in",
                remote: "Alleen namen uit de suggestielijst zijn toegestaan",
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Vul minimaal {0} tekens in."),
            },
            vak:  {
                required: "U dient een vak in te vullen",
                remote: "Alleen vakken uit de suggestielijst zijn toegestaan",
            },
            klas: {
                required: "Vul een klas in",
                remote: "Alleen klassen uit de suggestielijst zijn toegestaan"
            },
            'll-naam': "Voer de naam van de leerling in",
            datum: "Selecteer een terugkomdatum"
        }

    });

    $('input, textarea').placeholder({
        blankSubmit:true
    });


    $( "#docent" ).autocomplete({
        source: "handlers/autocompleteDocent.php",
        autoFill: true,
        matchCase: true
    });

    $( "#vak" ).autocomplete({
        source: "handlers/autocompleteVak.php",
        autoFill: true,
        matchCase: true
    });
    $( "#klas" ).autocomplete({
        source: "handlers/autocompleteStamgroep.php",
        autoFill: true,
        matchCase: true
    });
    $('#ll-naam').focus(function(){
        var url = 'handlers/autocompleteLeerling.php?stamgroep='+document.getElementById('klas').value;
        $(this).autocomplete('destroy');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            autoFill: true,
            matchCase: true
        });
    })

    $( "#datum" ).datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "style/images/icon_calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        monthNames: ['Januari','Februari','Maart','April','Mei','Juni','Juli','Augustus','September','Oktober','November','December'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Zo', 'Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za'],
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrBlockDay
    });

    $('#newap-error').hide();
    $("#submit-succes").delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
});

</script>
```

And the form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="newAp" class="form">
        <div class="alert alert-error" id="newap-error">
            <p>Corrigeer de rood gemarkeerde velden</p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="form-title">Leerling aanmelden</h2>
        <label for="docent">Docent</label>
        <input type="text" name="docent" id="docent" placeholder="Vul uw achternaam in"/>

        <label for="vak">Vak</label>
        <input type="text" name="vak" id="vak" placeholder="Vul de naam van het vak in"  />

        <label for="klas">Klas (stamgroep)</label>
        <input type="text" name="klas" id="klas" placeholder="Klas van de leerling" value="" data-dependency="ll-naam" />

        <label for="ll-naam">Leerling</label>
        <input type="text" name="ll-naam" id="ll-naam" placeholder="Naam van de leerling" disabled data-dependency="klas" />
        <label class="error" id="ll-naamErrorLabel">Vul eerst de klas in</label>

        <label for="opmerking">Opmerking</label>
        <textarea name="opmerking" name="opmerking" placeholder="Opmerking voor de surveillant."> </textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="opmerking_ph" value="Opmerking voor de surveillant." />

        <label for="date">Terugkom datum</label>
        <input type="text" name="datum" id="datum" readonly='true' placeholder="Klik om datum te selecteren" />

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Opslaan" />

    </form>
```

Comment: I cant fix your problem but I can tell you that you spelled success wrong.  "validClass: 'succes'" should be success with an extra s

Comment: That is just a CSS class, so it does't change a thing in the errors I'm getting. But thanks anyway, I will change that typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution. As far as I can tell, or how I see it, all these errors are related to the way jquery.validate works.

Having taken only a quick look at the plugin I can't really tell what's going wrong but I see significant difference between your implementation and for instance the one in the example on: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQueryValidateExample.aspx.

I have a couple of questions then, that you can probably answer more easily than me without doing more research (documentation on this plugin is fairly limited tbh):

1) How/when does validation actually get initiated? (because atm, there is validation going on before the autocomplete, which logically returns unnecessary errors).

2) What do highlight/unhighlight options do? Since I can't find any version of the validation plugin that support these options, I was just wondering.

I suspect the validation plugin is somewhat outdated and buggy. Implementation could be the problem too. Correct me if I'm wrong :). Let's see if the answers get me further.

Cheers

Comment: He Pim, thanks a lot for helping out! The validation isn fired on blur and on submit. You're right, there might be a thing about the autocomplete. But I still need to use both validation and autocomplete, to make sure users fill in the right stuff. Your second question: highlight is what should happen when a field is marked invalid; unhighligt does the opposite

Comment: I think it would greatly help if you could separate validation and auto completion.

Comment: *accidental submit of previous comment ;)*

At the moment what I think is going wrong early on is that input is submitted for completion which fires the validation. Instead you'd want auto completion to be handled first after which validation is fired. This could be done by firing validation from the auto completion script (on success).

I'd start with creating a validation trigger. You can then add listeners that fire the validation and customize them in such a way that they do not interfere with auto completion.

Just a step in the right direction.

Comment: just tried stripping out autocomplete out of the form. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything regadering the problems earlier mentioned :(

Comment: Okay, smart way to check that :). 

I wonder, what does the validator check as input in the case of entering "t" as input and selecting Smidt as teacher?

You could check this by alerting/console.log-ing the var/array that's input in jquery.validate.

Comment: Maybe this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/dhunink/Ta5WF/2/ I Could check that out for you later today. If you would be able to help me out, would be very very thankful. Looks like no one else can. If you prefer Skyping is also okay with me, or just sending you the code and stuff

Comment: By the way, I guess that case is pretty straight forward. When entering a T he validates directly as invalid; after selecting schmidt he still validates invalid, after onblur he validates valid.